# local and global variable usage in Python

Tags: python, list, global-variables, reverse, local-variables

I am testing a reverse function. My code is as follow:

```
def deep_reverse(L):

    new_list = []
    for element in L:
        new_list += [element[::-1]]
    L = new_list[::-1]


L = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
deep_reverse(L)
print(L)
```

I expect my output L can be like [[7, 6, 5], [4, 3], [2, 1]], but it only works inside my function.

I wasn't able to change it in the global variable. How can I make it happen? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L` is just a local variable, and assigning a new object to it won't change the original list; all it does is point the name `L` in the function to another object. See [Ned Batchelder's excellent explanation about Python names](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

You could replace all elements *in* the list `L` references by assigning to the `[:]` identity slice instead:

```
L[:] = new_list[::-1]
```

However, mutable sequences like lists have a [`list.reverse()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), so you can just reverse the list in-place with that:

```
L.reverse()
```

Do the same for each sublist:

```
def deep_reverse(L):
    """ assumes L is a list of lists whose elements are ints
    Mutates L such that it reverses its elements and also 
    reverses the order of the int elements in every element of L. 
    It does not return anything.
    """
    for element in L:
        element.reverse()
    L.reverse()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps me a lot with your explanation!